# Create 3D line instead of a thin line in Unity in runtime with mouse drag

Tags: unity

I know how to use line renderer to drag and drop to create line in runtime, but the line appears to be thin when looking from the end of the line, I want to create a real line that has a thickness(think of it as a tube or pipe shape), no mater where the look direction is, they should has a thinkness. How would you achieve this effect, I've got two ideas,

1.Create a rectangle shape, then extrude this shape to create mesh during runtime, but the manipulation of mesh during runtime is too complicated for me.

or

2.Create prefabs, and spawn new prefabs and connect them along the cursor routing to make them looked as they were a continous line.

Would you suggest me of some new ideas or existing package to achieve this effect, or is the first option is the way to go? What I want to do is to make a shader editor like appearence in 3D space, what I need to create is the edges, and the edges should look 3D instead of 2D line.

Comment: Does the line need to bend? Or, if we’re being technical, lines do not bend- curves bend. Is it a line or a curve (like a spline)?

Comment: It is curved lines but stay still, it is instrument wire

Answer (score 0):

What about using an actual 3d model? If you're not looking for something super detailed, you could create a cylinder shaped 3D model, and then replicate that over the course of the line. The overlaps wont look pretty, depending on how sharp the bends are, but it might achieve the look you're going for.

If you wanted to get a little bit better detail, you could have a few different versions of the model with different "end caps". Imagine a sharp 90 turn... you could use 2 cylinders where there ends are "cut off" at a 45 degree angle, meaning they would match up precisely. Even if you have some smoother curves, something like this could smooth over issues where it looks like one "pipe" is sticking through the other.